# Spring Boot WAR deployed in Tomcat 7 tries to perform weird automatic @Resource lookup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a deployable WAR using Spring Boot 1.2.5 and tried to deploy it in Tomcat 7.0.69. What happens is a really weird set of errors, looks like every @Resource annotation I used in the code for dependency injection beans is being looked up via JNDI:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter externalProviderAuthenticationFilter
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name   [com.graffitab.server.api.authentication.ExternalProviderAuthenticationFi lter/userService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com.graffitab.server.api.authentication.ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:449)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4830)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5510)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I defined that filter as:

```
@Log4j2
public class ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter extends  AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

@Resource
private UserService userService;

@Resource(name = "delegateJacksonHttpMessageConverter")
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter;


public ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/externalproviders/login", "POST"));
}
```

...

in a configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter externalProviderAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter externalProviderFilter =
                                            new ExternalProviderAuthenticationFilter();
    externalProviderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    externalProviderFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(storeSessionJsonLoginSuccessHandler());
    externalProviderFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(jsonLoginFailureHandler());
    return externalProviderFilter;
}
```

Why is standalone Tomcat confused about the @Resource? It also tries to lookup the datasource. The app is working fine when running embedded Tomcat, but I need it to work in an embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Resource` is a generic java annotation with a meaning to Tomcat:

- [Tomcat 7: JNDI Resources HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

and also a meaning to Spring:

- [6.9.7 `@Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-resource-annotation)

`@Bean` on the other hand is a spring-only DI annotation and Tomcat won't interfere.

The simplest solution for you would be to use Spring's `@Autowired` annotation (`@Inject` might work too). Tomcat will ignore these.

Your other option would be to disable that behavior in Tomcat, I think it's the [`enableNaming` option](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

Comment: Thanks, the useNaming property in context.xml did tje trick. Never seen this behavior before and been deploying Spring apps in Tomcat for years. I wonder if the absence of web.xml and Spring Boot workflow exposes beans differently. Will do a bit more testing and accept the answer.

Comment: @DavidFernandez I guess this happens before spring even initializes, wouldn't it crash should result in 2 beans, one spring managed, one tomcat managed.

Comment: I agree, it has to crash, I am just surprised I've never came across this before, with regular WARs with classic Spring apps deployed in Tomcat 6,7,8 using @Resource and no special config around auto-discover of naming.

Comment: @DavidFernandez Should be possible since servlet 2.5 includes optional support for jsr 250 annotations http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071393/java-web-development/new-features-added-to-servlet-2-5.html ,  which as far as I can find were supported since tomcat 6 https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-6  - same problem with [`@PostConstruct`](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201103.mbox/%3CAANLkTi=RU13O6qjvZ1orHSE8AhnBKRKD7ozct+W=ruun@mail.gmail.com%3E)