# Broaleaf 5.2 ROOT.war issue with Filters

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to deploy Broadleaf demo site version 5.2.0 on external tomcat 8.5.16 with MYSQL as DB and standalone external Solr server running on port 8983.

I am able to access the admin application.

When I try deploying the  ROOT.war, I get error

```
    12-Aug-2017 16:33:52.733 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting 
    filter [blDeviceResolverRequestFilter] 
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [blDeviceResolver] is not bound 
    in this Context. Unable to find [blDeviceResolver].
```

I tried creating a bean so that it autowires correctly in 
BroadleafDeviceResolverRequestFilter as

```
    @Bean(name="blDeviceResolver")
    public DeviceResolver getDeviceResolver() {
       return new LiteDeviceResolver();
    }
```

But the error is still the same and I am unable to run the demo application.

Comment: Resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

So the issues was that class BroadleafDeviceResolverRequestFilter was using

```
@Resource
private DeviceResolver deviceResolver;
```

But @Resource annotation is generic and means different things to Tomcat and Spring (Reference: [Spring Boot WAR deployed in Tomcat 7 tries to perform weird automatic @Resource lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690617/spring-boot-war-deployed-in-tomcat-7-tries-to-perform-weird-automatic-resource))

I replaced @Resource with @Autowired and added a bean to com.community.core.config.CoreConfig

```
@Bean(name="blDeviceResolver")
public DeviceResolver getDeviceResolver() {
   return new LiteDeviceResolver();
}
```

and my issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the report, and yes you have the right fix.

Comment: I am updating this in the framework, just pushed up a fix for this in Broadleaf at https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/pull/1620#issuecomment-322073859. Also, this would've only manifested itself when deploying on standalone Tomcat, that's how we missed it.